# Plotting Graphs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to plot these values against time. Y are prices of an stock index and X are given in dates. When I highlight both the columns and insert line graph. The graph turns out wrong. Not sure why. Need some guidance.

```
Y
55.86
56.4831183
56.79287172
56.15020358
56.54651172
57.17813626
57.74751614
57.99484875
57.81842842
57.82525099

X
19620702
19620703
19620705
19620706
19620709
19620710
19620711
19620712
19620713
19620716
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me when I select a Scatter plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your "Y" column only, and then insert the graph:

[image]

Then right-click the chart and select "Select Data...", and the *Select Data Source* dialog will open:

[image]

For the *Horizontal Axis Labels*, click "Edit", and this will open an *Axis Labels* dialog:

[image]

While that's open, go back to the spreadsheet and select your "X" column.  This will populate the dialog box with a range.

Hit "OK" to close that dialog, and then hit "OK" again to close the *Select Data Source* dialog.

That should do it:

[image]

Comment: This treats the X-axis data as text labels, rather than dates or numbers. Note that the gap between 02 and 03 is the same as the gap between 03 and 05.

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure what you're getting at?  "Labels" are always going to be "text".  I'm just using the example data provided.  The problem with the graphic that was there, was because I accidentally included the actual "X" cell, so it was the first X data point.  fixed...

Comment: See [Drawing a line graph in Excel with a numeric x-axis](http://superuser.com/q/667044/150988) for an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the X-Y-plot diagram (screenshot from danish version of Exell, but you should get the point).

[image]

Comment: tried this already. not able to get the date in the X column.